# Error during docker build of rust-backend-image from Postgres.rs

Tags: postgresql, docker, rust

I am going through the Docker Docs Guides/Language-specific guides/Rust/Develop your app
In step Docker build using the command given, from the directory of the cloned git sample app. Here is what I am executing as the build command - `docker build -t rust-backend-image .` it is failing to build with these errors.

```
    Compiling react-rust-postgres v0.1.0 (/app)                                                                                                                                          
0.358 error: couldn't read src/../migrations/0001_create-users_up.sql: No such file or directory (os error 2)                                                                                 
0.358  --> src/postgres.rs:8:9
0.358   |
0.358 8 |         include_str!("../migrations/0001_create-users_up.sql"),
0.358   |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
0.358   |
0.358   = note: this error originates in the macro `include_str` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
0.358 
0.358 error: couldn't read src/../migrations/0002_add-root-user-to-users_up.sql: No such file or directory (os error 2)
0.358   --> src/postgres.rs:12:9
0.358    |
0.358 12 |         include_str!("../migrations/0002_add-root-user-to-users_up.sql"),
0.358    |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
0.358    |
0.358    = note: this error originates in the macro `include_str` (in Nightly builds, run with -Z macro-backtrace for more info)
0.358 
0.421 error: could not compile `react-rust-postgres` (bin "react-rust-postgres") due to 2 previous errors
------
Dockerfile:23
```

I have pulled everything down as per instruction. I recently did a `rustup update`. I am running on a MacBook Pro pre M1 chip. I did try to edit the `include_str` by removing one of the dots to no avail. I am not sure why it is not finding these files as I am able to from the terminal using the same relative path.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hard to say for sure, but the goal is to build the Rust application within the Docker image, right? It sounds like you haven't copied your `migrations/` directory into the image. You're likely missing a [`COPY`](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#copy) instruction in your dockerfile to do this.

Comment: Aha, I went back and looked at the dockerfile and did add the copy instruction and voila?

Answer (score 0):

Add line `--mount=type=bind,source=migrations,target=migrations \` after `--mount=type=bind,source=src,target=src \` in Dockerfile. Inspired by the comment from kmdreko.